# Checkbox array in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

Im trying to create a array of Checkboxes in Winforms and I  have four Checkboxes and if I click on a Checkbox, a messagebox should display the checkboxes checked.

```
 public void checkboxtest()
    {

        CheckBox[] boxes = new CheckBox[4];
        boxes[0] = checkBox1;
        boxes[1] = checkBox2;
        boxes[2] = checkBox3;
        boxes[3] = checkBox4;


        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
        {

                if (boxes[i].Checked == true && boxes[i].Enabled)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("boxes[i] is clicked");
                }

        }
    }

    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkboxtest();
    }

    private void checkBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkboxtest();
    }
```

continues for 3 and 4 too...

How should I go about it ?? 
Thanks.

Comment: Why don't use events, You are doing it entirely wrong!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop termination should be `i < 4`, not `i <= 4` since your array only has 4 elements.  Also `boxes[i].Checked == true` is redundant, you can just say `boxes[i].Checked`.

If you want to display the checked checkboxes when you toggle the state, you'll need to add an event handler to them (to handle the [`CheckBox.CheckChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checkedchanged.aspx) event):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _checkBoxes = new CheckBox[] { _checkBox1, _checkBox2, _checkBox3, _checkBox4 };

        foreach (var checkBox in _checkBoxes)
            checkBox.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(ShowCheckedCheckboxes);
    }

    void ShowCheckedCheckboxes(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string message = string.Empty;

        for (int i = 0; i < _checkBoxes.Length; i++)
        {
            if (_checkBoxes[i].Checked && _checkBoxes[i].Enabled)
            {
                message += string.Format("boxes[{0}] is clicked\n", i);
            }
        }

        MessageBox.Show(message);
    }

    CheckBox[] _checkBoxes;
}
```

Comment: @ Chris Schmich: thank you so much. 
What if I need to add a button and then display this 'message' inside 'MessageBox.Show(message);'. So if I click on the button, the messae box should be displayed instead of displaying while I check on a box.

Comment: @SLp: I strongly recommend reading about events in Windows Forms: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h12f09z.aspx  It's well worth your time since events are everywhere in .NET.  For your question, though, you should look at the `Button.Click` event (which is inherited from the `Control` class): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.click.aspx